# Create a thumbnail screenshot of a website that is submitted to website directory

Tags: thumbnail, screenshot

I would like to know how to set the thumbnail of a screenshot of a website when someone submits that site to my directory. It would need to be automatically generated.

[See an example](http://netscripter.org/example.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a good service to do this but I'm afraid it's not available in English (only French or Spanish): http://robothumb.com.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).

Selenium is a browser automation scripting framework with an API so that it can be called from a variety of programming languages.   It allows you to remote control Firefox:

- Create a new window of a specific size
- Open a URL in that window
- Save the visible portion of the webpage to an image (like a screenshot)

To make this work on a server, you have to get [Firefox running "headless" in a virtual frame buffer](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/).